# Open data on buildings in Montreal

Tags: shapefile, data, gml, kmz, canada

Is there a resource for open data for the City of Montreal?

I am specifically looking for building footprints.

Comment: Where have you tried looking?

Comment: I think the logical place to ask about open data is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about shapefiles, but a basemap dataset ("cartographie de base") is provided here:

http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/cartographie-de-base

It's available in DWG format and contains a buildings layer:[image: sample data]

Answer (score 3):

You can download the 2015 LiDAR data (including buildings - class 6) [here](http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/lidar-aerien-2015).

3d models of buildings for certain boroughs are available [here](http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/maquette-numerique-batiments-citygml-lod2-avec-textures) and [here](http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/maquette-numerique-plateau-mont-royal-batiments-lod2-avec-textures).

You can also get OpenStreetMap extracts for Montreal from MapZen [here](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/metro/montreal_canada/).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't downloaded to verify, but a google search finds:

https://www.concordia.ca/library/guides/geospatial-data/geodata.html.html :

> "CanVec is a multi-source product coming mainly from the National
>   Topographic Data Base (NTDB), the GeoBase initiative (www.geobase.ca)
>   and the data update using Landsat 7 imagery coverage. CanVec provides
>   topographic information in vector format and contains more than 90
>   topographical entities thematically organized into 11 distribution
>   themes: Administrative Boundaries, **Buildings and Structures**, Energy,
>   Hydrography, Industrial and Commercial Areas, Places of Interest,
>   Relief and Landforms, Toponymy, Transportation, Vegetation and Water
>   Saturated Soils."

Which can be downloaded @ 
http://ftp.geogratis.gc.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/vector/canvec/shp/
Or more specifically for Quebec: http://ftp.geogratis.gc.ca/pub/nrcan_rncan/vector/canvec/shp/ManMade/canvec_50K_QC_ManMade_shp.zip   (44mb)